# standard curl like access from dotnet

Tags: .net

Is there any library in dotnet that transforms a 'normal' request string to a proper request?

Something that would automate things like

```
 client.Headers.[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] <- "Basic " + un + ":" + pw;
```

Comment: What kind of app are you writing?

Comment: just writing a simple script, and I must be doing something wrong : there has to be a simple way to issue a simple http auth request... right now having Networkcredential, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient`, there is the `Credentials` property. You can write:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Don't know of anything similar for use with `HttpClient`.

Comment: indeed, this works, thank you... but are there no standard dotnet class that support standard web format ?

Comment: @nicolas: Don't know what you mean by "standard Web format." As I understand it, setting the `Credentials` property that way ends up setting the `Authorization` header in the outgoing request.

Comment: I was under the impression that everyone commonly used "prot://username:pwd@machine". At least it is pretty widespread in the unix world !

Comment: @nicolas: It may be widespread in the unix world, but the HTTP spec expects it in the Authorization header.

Comment: so you are saying that it tries to put conformance to standard first. and standard on the web is not defined by whatever unix has been doing for the last 30 years. man, that's belief.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just writing a script, why can't you just use curl? It works in windows. http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: Indeed, but I was already in a F# scripting environment, so was wondering what part was missing. I really thought I was missing something, and looking at other question on SO, I am not alone..